# Is it possible to measure computer components power consumption in software?

Tags: hardware

I was wandering if (most common) motherboards provide hardware capabilities for measuring the exact power, expanded by the individual components - CPU, RAM, WiFi, etc.

<sup>As voltages are read and directly available e.g. in BIOS, I reckon that similar interface may be provided for the power consumption as well.</sup>

Comment: Probably not (at least not at the individual component level). At the system level, you can (e.g. with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acpi etc..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching Google for `fedora18 power optimization` pops up a nice guide. Inside, [**PowerTOP**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerTOP) is recommended and it's use is described. The program "is a software utility designed to measure, explain and minimise a computer's electrical power consumption", and this is as close as it gets to answering my question. Voila.